# C# - How to temporary stream file online to be accessed URL

Tags: c#, .net, file, server, stream

I have been working on project recently where eventually I need two (or more) applications on different machines to be able to access the same file on one of them without uploading it to a server first.

Thus, the best idea I could get was to create something like a mini-temporary file server where the desired file path is streamed over the ip address and the other machine can access it via a URL like that "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/path/file.ext".

I have a good experience with C# but this approach... I never stepped into before, so any help is appreciated either in achieving this approach or any other method that can lead to allowing cross-internet access to a file on a machine.

Thanks in advance.

**[Edit]
This operation has to be done without prior port forwarding, I don't know if this is possible, but I guess if it is not then I might need to do something like streaming to a php server first or something, again any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [virtual directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) pointing to a local directory in IIS.

1. Application A writes file to local directory.
2. Application B reads
   file from http.

Otherwise, you could use a network drive for both applications to read/write from.

Comment: For the IIS, I never worked with it before and I don't really know how it works, will I be able to have a temporary server for example that is ended after the application is closed ? will this generate me a url that I can share across the internet without prior port forwarding ?

Also network drive is not an option, as the file will always be on a machine and I need to share it publicly on the internet, not only locally.